# Can CSOM set portal url of a site collection?

Tags: client-object-model

Can CSOM be used to set the portal url of a site collection?

This is possible using server-side object model via SPSite.PortalUrl:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.portalurl(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not exposed as part of the CSOM api: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.site_members(v=office.15).aspx